# dplyr: rearrange one row dataframe to multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have a few small data frames each with one row that are results from a mediation analysis. I need to rearrange the cells to be three rows, each with two of the variables and their corresponding coefficient. Example below:

HAVE DATA:

```
lab_x lab_m lab_y    coef_xm    coef_my   coef_xy
    x     m     y   -0.21***    0.08*** -0.084***
```

WANT DATA:

```
var1   var2        coef
   x      m    -0.21***
   m      y     0.08***
   x      y   -0.084***
```

**UPDATE**

Changing the data slightly, I need to keep the variable names that appear originally in the DF

```
df<-read.table(text="lab_x lab_m lab_y    coef_xm    coef_my   coef_xy
    v1    v2        v3  -0.21***    0.08*** -0.084***", header = TRUE)
```

WANT:

```
 var1    var2        coef
   v1      v2    -0.21***
   v2      v3     0.08***
   v1      v3   -0.084***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data's in that consistent format, you could hard code the reshaping:

```
data.frame(var1 = c(df[1,1], df[1,2], df[1,1]), 
           var2 = c(df[1,2], df[1,3], df[1,3]),
           coef = as.character(df[1,4:6]))


  var1 var2      coef
1   v1   v2  -0.21***
2   v2   v3   0.08***
3   v1   v3 -0.084***
```

Or more obscurely:

```
v <- \(i) {as.character(df[1,i])} 
data.frame(var1 = v(c(1,2,1)), var2 = v(c(2,3,3)), coef = v(c(4:6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can do extract the name of the coefficient columns, get the corresponding `lab` names and create a dataframe.

```
col1 <- grep('coef', names(df), value = TRUE)
col2 <- sub('coef_', '', fixed = TRUE, cols)

do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(col2, ''), function(x) 
  setNames(df[paste0('lab_', x)], c('var1', 'var2')))) |>
  transform(coef = unlist(df[col1], use.names = FALSE))

#  var1 var2      coef
#1   v1   v2  -0.21***
#2   v2   v3   0.08***
#3   v1   v3 -0.084***
```

Comment: This works for the coefficients, but I actually need to keep the original variable names that vary in different data sets. See update, for example.

Comment: I think I had misunderstood the question. See the update if that helps.